# How to push values to list in theamleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im trying push object into List im able to push value to normal fields,
Following is the code for binding value i have used:
Job Model

```
public class Job {
    public Job(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Candidate Model

```
public class Candidate {
    
    private String candidatename;
    private List<Job> jobs;
    
    public String getCandidatename() {
        return candidatename;
    }

    public void setCandidatename(String candidatename) {
        this.candidatename = candidatename;
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }
}
```

candidatedetail.html

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/savejobhistory}" method="post" th:object="${candidate}">
        <label>Candidate name:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{candidatename}" /><br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

candidatejob.html

```
    <h2>Candidate Details!</h2>
    <span>Note:</span><span th:text="${candidate.candidatename}"></span><br/>
```

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/emp")
public String test(Model model) {
    Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
    model.addAttribute("candidate", candidate);
    return "candidatedetail";
}

@PostMapping("/savejobhistory")
public String sendForm(@ModelAttribute("candidate") Candidate candidate) {
    System.out.println("Inisde Meth");
    System.out.println(candidate.getCandidatename());
    return "candidatejob";
}
```

how to push to list i tried following and failed

```
<input type="text" 
                placeholder='Company Name'  class="form-control" th:field="*{candidate.jobs}" th:value="${job.name}"/></td>
                    <label th:text="${job.name}"></label>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf is server side. If you want to add dynamic content, the easy way is use javascript or jquery for dom manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial can help explain how to index into an array when using a form.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields)  `th:field="*{jobs[${0}].name}"` is incorrect.  If you want to specify the index it should look like this:

```
th:field="*{jobs[0].name}"
```

or if you want to use a variable:

```
th:field="*{jobs[__${variable}__].name}"
```

(you must use double underscores `__` to do preprocessing in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use for each using the following format as an example :

```
        <tr th:each="Jobs : ${yourJobList}">
            <td><span th:text="${job.yourjobfield1}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${job.yourjobfield2}"></span></td>
        </tr>
```

This will multiply the above block of elements for each job in your list.

Comment: i need to capture the input as text field @John Kim

Comment: @Prameshwar What do you mean capture? Are you saying you want to pass jobs list from the website to your backend?

Comment: yes to accept the input map it to list 
                                    <input type="text" required class="form-control" th:maxlength="90" th:field="*{jobs[__${0}__].name}" /> but this wont work